# Business Logic + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, repository, data-access-layer, business-logic

I've an MVC application, which is divided into 3 layers:
- Presentation - ASp.NET MVC
- Busines Logic - Here we have entities and object services. We alo have mappers between DAL objects and BL objects
- Data Access Layer - we use EF to query the database.
Now, we've created a factory for object services, and the factory is injected into presentation later using Unity. Each time I want to do some logic, I call an appropriate service which uses DAL repositories to do some stuff. 
Now, silly question, let suppose that I want to check if I can add a user with a provided nickname. The nickname is unique in the database, so before I add the user, I check if a user with provided nickname exists. So, it's a simple query that returns true/false. Becuase I don't have any connections between presentation layer and business layer, I check it in the service. But the code of the service method simply looks like:

```
var exists = repository.NicknameExists(nickname);
return exists;
```

The code above is strange, because it does nothing, just calls a method and returns its value. On the other hand, I've Separation of Concerns, so my solution is well organised. Can someone give me some suggestions, how should I solve problems like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem here. It's perfect method for me:

```
public bool IsUserExists(string nickname)
{
    return repository.NicknameExists(nickname);
}
```

I would recomend to you to read this [blog post](http://blog.nathandelane.com/2010/02/patterns-and-practices-valid-reasons-to.html) about valid reasons to create a routine or the chapter 7.1 of the [Code Complete 2ed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)

Comment: Could it possibly be renamed to 'DoesUserNicknameExist' so my inner grammar Nazi doesn't explode? ;)